# fadeIn, fadeOut and moveTo actions don't work on Actors

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I have a stack which I'm filling with tables . I'm trying to fadeIn, fadeOut, moveTo, several of these actors but the addAction methods don't work:

```
    stack_stage = new Stack();      
    table_menu = new Table();
    level_selector = new ex01MenuLevelSelectorBase(skin, table_menu);       

    table_menu.add(level_selector).center();
    table_menu.setFillParent(true);

    stack_stage.setFillParent(true);
    stack_stage.add(table_menu);
    stage.addActor(stack_stage);

    table_level_selector = new Table();
    image_level_selector = new Image(skin.getDrawable("hud-level5"));
    image_level_selector.setColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f);
    table_level_selector.add(image_level_selector);     

    stack_stage.addActor(table_level_selector);

    //doesn't work 
    table_level_selector.addAction(com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.fadeOut(5f));

    //works
    table_level_selector.addAction(com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.hide());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
table_level_selector.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.fadeOut(5f),Actions.hide ()));
```

or

```
table_level_selector.addAction(Actions.sequence(
                              com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.fadeOut(5f),
                              com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.hide ()));
```

is likely that this is your mistake, try this in the render method

```
stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

Comment: Why should I try fadeout(0f) when hide works? Anyway , I tried that sequence with fadeout(5f) and it simply waits 5 seconds without changing alpha then the actor dissapears just as it would by simply calling hide().

Comment: Yeah, but I put fadeOut(0f) separately not in a sequence, sorry for the confusion . My point was that fadeIn, fadeOut , moveTo , etc don't work with actions added to the stage before or after .

Comment: @gogonapel sequence is not parallel, parallel is another type, however, I test my code works

Comment: @gogonapel try to test only a single table within a state do not use your class Stack aver if the error comes from an ahi esta look image_level_selector.setColor (1f, 1f, 1f, 0.5f); this 0.5f will not make a behavior, unwanted convinacion with fadeout

Comment: I need the stack though!

Comment: @gogonapel yes but to rule out the error in addition, you can create a screen just to test that part, just a table and stage

Comment: Adding the table to the stage directly didn't change the issue.

Comment: I have that added already ! fadeIN fadeOUT dont work, moveTo, moveBy work.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but today I encountered the same and problem and realized that I hadn't  added

```
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

in the render method. This caused my image to draw over itself:

1. When it faded in it took less than I expected (because the alphas were adding)
2. When it faded out the image didn't change (because there was the same image underneath)

I know this isn't your case, but this error took me some time to figure out what wasn't working just to discover this little oversight!